# Is it possible to generate and create your own seed?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to create your very own Minecraft seed or map just by prompting the game with what you specifically want?
For example, a bunch of island each with 2 biomes and each island is like 80 blocks away from each other. If there is a way to do this please explain how.

Comment: I don't think so. You can have over 18 quintillion of seeds in Minecraft, which is A LOT, but there may be combinations that can't be generated in the exact way you want them.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge of Minecraft seed generation, it is not possible to get that level of detail unless you build it yourself or get very lucky in generating a world. Some advice I would give is to find articles that feature a seed similar to what you are looking for, such as this one https://tryhardguides.com/minecraft-survival-island-seeds/. The keyword that I think would help you find what you are looking for is survival island. Another possible solution is using https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/seed-map and searching for the seed that way.

If you are curious about why you can't specifically query what you want in the generation of a Minecraft world, I can recommend some resources.

1. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)
2. https://www.davidepesce.com/2020/02/24/procedural-generation-in-game-development/
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

The first two links are in the terms of video games making it a much easier read than the last one, which is solely the math behind procedural generation.